# Как расставить запятые в предложении: "Надеемся наше творение поднимет вам настроение"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Надеемся наше творение поднимет вам настроение.

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить запятые.

Answer (score 1):

**Надеемся, наше творение поднимет вам настроение.**

В данном случае ***надеемся*** является вводным словом, которое обособляется.

Другой вариант с тем же содержанием: *Надеемся, что наше творение поднимет вам настроение.* Это уже сложноподчиненное предложение, запятая ставится перед изъяснительным союзом ЧТО.

Answer (score 0):

**Надеемся** — в данном предложении слово является вводным, выделяется запятой.
Это слово грамматически не связано с другими членами предложения (то есть от него и к нему невозможно задать синтаксический вопрос), поэтому оно не является членом предложения; его можно изъять, не исказив смысла.
Это вводное слово выражает предположение, допущение, неуверенность.

**Надеемся, наше творение поднимет вам настроение.**
*Надеемся, наш ответ поможет вам.*

Мне кажется, что вопрос о пунктуации мог возникнуть в связи с тем, что в речи чаще всего употребляется вводное слово *надеюсь* (1 л., ед. ч.). Наше же слово *надеемся* — это глагол в форме первого лица мн. числа. Правила обособления этих вводных слов совершенно одинаковые.

Об особенностях пунктуации можно прочитать здесь:
[Когда запятой выделяется слово «НАДЕЮСЬ»?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/zapyatoy-vyidelyaetsya-slovo-nadyeus.html)